# XCode12: How to set up constraints in an image to make it responsive to an screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, responsive

[image: XCode12 screen Storyboard 1]

I'm having issues with constraints in XCode 12: Even if I describe accurately all measures involved, there is no way apparently to resize a 850x600 image to make it fit proportionally in the screen of an apple device. As you can see in the image, the constraints are defined to make the original image fit WITH BORDERS on the Iphone's screen, but nevertheless is turns out to be a disaster afterwards...

As you can see in the screen capture, the image overflows the screen when the model device is changed. So...we have a problem. And the answer or clue that I'm seeking night and day is...
[image: With another device]

How to make this image to become RESPONSIVE to screen size, and keep it's proportions. No way how the hell something so basic is so difficult in XCode...

must edit... look how the alignment constrainst are shown in grey...no idea why...this avoids me to try the solution provided by the good fellow above...
[image: grey list of options]

Comment: Please remove unnecessary emotives and false claims ("no way", "how the hell", etc).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you've defined constraints to center the imageView and having it a size of 850x600 pixels. This will keep the image of that exact same size, regardless the device it is shown on.

If you want the image to shrink, keeping the aspect ration you need to define constraint for the top, bottom, leading and trailing edge.

And you need to set the imageView's contentMode to "Aspect Fit", which is the default, afaik.

This is an image shown on an iPhone 11:
[image: iPhone 11]

And this the same image shown on an iPhone 4s:
[image: iPhone 4s]

Edit:

One way to add those constraints is to select (highlight) the imageView and click on the button with the little square in the middle surrounded by those "T"s. :-)

[image: Add constraints]

Comment: As you can see in the edit I've just made to the question, I'm unable to provide those constraints: They are impossible to select. They are listed in grey.....Why?

Comment: OK, I will try tomorrow